# NodeJs push in array not working within the async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await

Here is my code...

```
var schedule =new Schedule(
            {
                flightNumber: req.body.flightNumber,
                status: req.body.status,
                pickDateTime: req.body.pickDateTime,
            });

            if(req.body.passenger.length > 0){

                await req.body.passenger.forEach(async function (data) {
                    var driver
                    await Driver.findOneAndUpdate({area:data.location_code,$expr: { $gt:["$vehicle_capacity", "$capacity_occupied"]}},{ $inc: { capacity_occupied: +1 } }).then((drivers) => {
                        driver = drivers._id
                    });                 
                    await schedule.passenger.push({
                        driver: driver,
                        dropLocation: req.body.dropLocation,
                        droplong: req.body.droplong,
                        picklong: data.long
                    })
                });
            }
            console.log(schedule.passenger);
```

When I'm trying to access schedule.passenger inside the async function It's working but when trying to access outside the async function it's not working.

Comment: Duplicate [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Well, it is related to asynchronicity, I am unable to understand why are you using await in an array function. I am curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEach(async function` will fire bunch of async functions and once array iterations are complete, the execution will move to next code block without waiting for all the async functions to complete.

This can be taken care of by using `map` function and returning promises and wait for all those.

```
let allPromises = req.body.passenger.map(async function (data) {
 //your code goes here
});

Promise.allSettled(allPromises).then(() => {
 console.log(schedule.passenger);
});
```

Also `await schedule.passenger.push({` is not correct because `Array.prototype.push()` is not an async operation.

Comment: is it also related to the variable scope?

Comment: Which variable?

Comment: schedule.passenger, and also I am unable to see the passenger array in the object.

Comment: as `schedule` is at outer scope hence property can be added and will be available. But `await schedule.passenger.push({` is not correct because `Array.prototype.push()` is not an async ops.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath you are an awesome boy... You make my day thanks